# Create venn diagram in python with 4 circles

Tags: python, venn-diagram

How can I create a venn diagram in python from 4 sets? Seems like the limit in matplotlib is only 3?

```
from matplotlib_venn import venn3

v = venn3(
    [
        set(ether_list),
        set(bitcoin_list),
        set(doge_list),
    ],
)
```

Comment: "Seems like the limit in matplotlib is only 3" - Yes, because drawing it with 4 circles, each intersecting with each combination of the other 3 is impossible... You can draw it with more convoluted forms, like [this](https://math.gmu.edu/~eobrien/Venn4.html), but readability suffers...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Venn diagrams with circles can work only with <4 sets, because the geometrical properties of intersections (some won't be possible to show). Some python libraries that allow you to show venn diagrams with more exotic shapes are:

- [pyvenn](https://github.com/tctianchi/pyvenn)
- [venn](https://pypi.org/project/venn/)

Answer (score 3):

There is a new python 3 package venny4py that can create Venn diagrams with up to 4 sets. It can plot and save figure or plot it as a subplot of your own matplotlib figure, figure size and dpi adjustable.

Example:

```
pip install venny4py

from venny4py.venny4py import *

#dict of sets
sets = {
    'Set1': set(list("Harry Potter")),
    'Set2': set(list("Hermione Granger")),
    'Set3': set(list("Ron Weasley")),
    'Set4': set(list("Severus Snape"))}
    
venny4py(sets=sets)
```

[image: Venn diagram with 4 sets]

More details can be found [here](https://github.com/timyerg/venny4py)

Comment: Would be great if the sectors were representative of the respective cardinalities. Sill a nice tool, thanks!

Comment: @vonbecker, thank you for the feedback. You mean, indicate the number of all elements that are shared between groups in each intersection instead of elements, that are unique? Wouldn't it be a little bit confusing? In theory, I can add such option to the tool. It can be also calculated from txt output.

Comment: No, I was referring to making the *areas* of the sectors more proportional to the cardinalities they represent, like a Venn diagram should, in theory.

Comment: That's interesting. Didn't think about it. Maybe will add it in the future for 2-3 circles, but probably not for 4.